# Qual o tempo de vida de uma variável no método, na classe e no módulo?

Tags: python-3.x, escopo-de-variáveis, tempo-de-vida

Sei que uma variável declarada em um método dura enquanto durar o escopo do método. Como `python` tem o conceito de variáveis de classes, até quando dura uma variável declarada na classe? E uma variável declarada solta em um módulo, quando ela "nasce" e quando ela "morre"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variável vai existir enquanto houver uma referência a ela. No momento que o contador de referências chega a 0, a variável é apagada. Isso é independente de onde a referência reside - se dentro ou fora de uma classe.

Variáveis declaradas em módulos são criadas no momento que o código que as define é executado. Isso geralmente ocorre no momento que o módulo é importado, a não ser que alguma condição dentro do módulo impeça isso.

Uma "expressão idiomática" bastante comum em Python é essa:

```
# várias definições
# ........

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # executar algum código
    # .....

# fim do arquivo
```

Caso você defina uma variável dentro desse `if`, ela só será criada caso esse módulo seja executado diretamente em vez de importado. Os nomes definidos acima do if são inicializados tanto quando o módulo é importado quanto quando executado diretamente. Claro que o mesmo vale caso não existe esse `if`.

Variáveis globais ao módulo, em geral, existem para sempre, pois módulos importados têm mantidas referências a eles em `sys.modules`. Essa referência impede a coleta do lixo, então, a não ser que seu módulo seja removido diretamente de lá (usando `del`), variáveis definidas no módulo vão continuar existindo.